# Monopoly dice probabilities, including doubles

Tags: probability, dice

According to Monopoly, when you roll a set of doubles, you get to roll again.
So if we get 6;6, 5;5, 4;4, 3;3, 2;2, 1;1,  we will roll again. However, Monopoly has the "speeding" rule, this means that you go to jail after rolling three doubles. Theorically, it's possible to get to the 35 square by dice alone on your first turn. 6;6, 6;6, 6;5.
How can I calculate the probability of rolling to any square from "GO"?

1. Square 1- 0
2. Square 2- 0
3. Square 3- 2/36 (2;1 , 1;2)
4. Square 4- 2/36 (3;1 , 1;3)
5. Square 5- 4/36 (4;1, 1;4, 3;2, 2;3)  + X (2 (1;1) and then 3 (2/36))???

Thanks for reading

Comment: The computation is tedious. Most of it has to be done case by case, working your way down the tree of possibilities. Your answer for 3 isn't right yet. You might roll doubles and then 1:2.

Comment: @EthanBolker Wolfram's answer to 3 is fine. A double would get him at least to square 2, and the 1:2 would get him to at least square 5.

Comment: @Wolfram  probably easiest to work by cases.  First assume that no doubles are rolled (so you can only get so far as square 11)...easy to list those probabilities.  Now assume that exactly one double is rolled, so you can get to any square between #5 and #23.  Still not too  bad.  Now assume two doubles thrown.  Ok, that one is a bit messy.  But perfectly doabale.

Comment: I don't know if you're allowed to admit it on the mathematics site, but a coding language like python is pretty easy to pick up and use to generate such a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Square 5.** $$\frac{4}{36}+\frac{1}{36}\frac{2}{36}$$

Explaination. $\frac{1}{36}$ is the probability for (1,1). Then $\frac{2}{36}$ is the probability for either (2,1) or (1,2).

**Square 6.** $$\frac{4}{36}+\frac{1}{36}\frac{2}{36}$$

Just go case by case for this one.

**Square 7.**

$$\frac{6}{36}+\frac{1}{36}\frac{4}{36}+\frac{1}{36}\frac{2}{36}+\frac{1}{36}\frac{1}{36}\frac{2}{36}$$

Just go case by case for this one, first one throw, then two throws, first (1,1), then two throws, first (2,2), then three throws, first (1,1), then (1,1).

And so on. By working by cases, one can get the following graphs. There is a 1/216, approximately 0.00463, probability to get in jail.

[image]
[image]